# Remove fill-in color from histogram bars in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have plotted a histogram in MATLAB. The bars are appearing in blue by default. Is there any any to remove the fill-in color, and make it appear white instead?

Glad to receive any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup its `FaceColor`:

```
h = findobj(gca, 'Type', 'patch');
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'w')
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just choosing white as your colour

```
bar(data, 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the link below link.  You use the set function to set properties of the handle.  You choose which properties you set, and the ones you don't go to default.  The [1 1 1] in the code below makes the face color white. play around with those three numbers to find other colours.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html?searchHighlight=plot+histogram

```
hist(data)
h = findobj(gca,'Type','Patch');
set(h,'FaceColor',[1 1 1], 'EdgeColor','black');
```

-James